# Android Bluetooth BLE onDescriptorWrite GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a service that connects to a Bluetooth glucose device directly via the mac address.

```
if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {         
  if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {             
    return true;         
  } 
  else {             
    return false;         
  }     
}          
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
```

The pairing routine and downloading of data from the device work perfect the first time after pairing, but if I try to re-connect to the device and register for notifications I receive a GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION error in my BluetoothGatt.onDescriptorWrite method.

```
@Override
public void onDescriptorWrite (BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
    ...
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION) {
    ...
```

The system then prompts the user for a pin code and asks them to re-authenticate with the device, even though the BONDING STATE shows as BONDED.

I've read quite a few StackOverflow posts about BLE and some of them are conflicting or do not address the question of connection handling directly.

1. If we are trying to connect to a previously paired device, do we use
   auto connect or not?
2. Do we need to re-enable notifications for a
   device each time we connect to it? Or only the first time we
   connect?

The device I'm using is a Moto G with KitKat 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Lollipop fixed the problem. The authentication now works perfectly and I do not get prompted every time I create a new connection.